# Why LogbackMDC keep track of last operation?

Tags: java, logback, thread-local, mdc

I am looking at the implementation of [LogbackMDCAdapter](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/61ffd3aba042bbb22f588599ff5574d3b9667d22/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/util/LogbackMDCAdapter.java#L105), and it keeps track of `lastOperation` I don't understand the reason for doing this, anyone has an idea why this is done?

And, why `duplicateAndInsertNewMap` is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment [here](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/commit/4fa9166747fccbaed7f35a5c877d0aaaf41168c5#diff-e5a738c3ab37fbeacbb433d7d7171c51c6058623c377c8549191ad47ca5020f3L46) the map copying is required for serialization purposes

> Each time a value is added, a new instance of the map is created. This
> is to be certain that the serialization process will operate on the
> updated map and not send a reference to the old map, thus not allowing
> the remote logback component to see the latest changes.

This refers to the behaviour of `ObjectOutputStream` sending references to previously written objects instead of the full object, unless using the [writeUnshared](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared-java.lang.Object-) method.

It is not directly obvious why it's possible to skip copying unless there's a `get/put` combination, but apparently even if you have multiple `put` operations in a row, the serialization will work properly as long as the map is copied only when a `put/remove` is performed right after a `get`. So this is a [performance optimization](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-620) to avoid copying the map unnecessarily when putting several items in it.